# Shiny: update varSelectInput() using the column names of a global variable

Tags: r, shiny, global-variables

I have a shiny app, which reads a csv data table, and then processes the table and saves the processed data as a global variable `DFG` (I used **<<-** assignment operator to produce this global variable). This global variable will be used in another session for further data analysis.

In the new shiny session, I would like to access the column names of this global variable and use it to subset the data.

However, it did not work. It seems that the `varSelectInput()` cannot be updated.

When I tried with an R internal data `iris`, the code worked. I don't know what should I do to make it work for my global variable.

1. It works for `Iris` data

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  varSelectInput(inputId = "getColumn", label="Get Column", data = ""),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server = function(input, output, session){

  StatGroup <- reactive({
    return(as.character(input$getColumn))
  })
  
  updateVarSelectInput(inputId = "getColumn",
                       data = iris,
                       selected = "")
  
  output$table <- renderTable(iris[, StatGroup(), drop = FALSE])

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Basically what I want to do is something like this:

2. It does not work for my global data `DFG`

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  varSelectInput(inputId = "getColumn", label="Get Column", data = ""),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server = function(input, output, session){

  StatGroup <- reactive({
    return(as.character(input$getColumn))
  })

if(!exists(deparse(substitute(DFG)))) {DFG <- NULL} # this one does not work

  updateVarSelectInput(inputId = "getColumn",
                       data = DFG,
                       selected = "")
  
  output$table <- renderTable(iris[, StatGroup(), drop = FALSE])

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

3. This method works. But I don't understand why. This method is not ideal for me as I have no a prior information of user upload column names.

Suppose my `DFG` has two columns, named `Group1` and `Group2`

then if I add the code `DFG <- data.frame(Group1 = "", Group2 = "")`, and it worked.

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  varSelectInput(inputId = "getColumn", label="Get Column", data = ""),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server = function(input, output, session){

  StatGroup <- reactive({
    return(as.character(input$getColumn))
  })

  DFG <- data.frame(Group1 = "", Group2 = "") ## with this code, it worked
  
  updateVarSelectInput(inputId = "getColumn",
                       data = DFG,
                       selected = "")
  
  output$table <- renderTable(iris[, StatGroup(), drop = FALSE])

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Where exactly are you creating the `DFG` variable? How are you passing it to the shiny process? It sure seems like setting `DFG` equal to `NULL` is a problem. Are you sure the variable actually exists when the application is run?

Comment: @MrFlick, Thanks for your help. `DFG` is created in another shiny session. When the application run for the first time, it does not exist. But it exist after reading the user uploaded `csv table`.

Comment: Can you please update your example to be more clear on exactly how that happens. That part doesn't seem to make sense at the moment.  If you run `DFG <- NULL` in your server function, that will create a shadow variable that will mask the global variable so you'll never see the global value. You would need to create some sort of reactive variable that can change.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for your suggestion. I will re-prepare a **Minimal, Reproducible Example** later.

Comment: @MrFlick, I have updated my question. The 3rd example works, and the downstream statistics also works. so  I think the initial value of `DFG` is NULL may not be the reason.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are saying. It's still unclear where exactly you are setting the value of `DFG` in the 2nd example. What "downstream" statistics are you referring to? Why do you think the problem is not the NULL value? When exactly do you need to change the value of `DFG` in the their example? If you need to respond to user input, then you need to make `DFG` a reactive object that you can change over time. How do you want the application to behave until the `DFG` value is set up the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a plain old global variable to store the data, use a global reactive value that you define up front. Then when that gets updated, other sessions using it will be notified, too.

```r
library(shiny)

global_data <- reactiveVal(NULL)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("go", "Sample a dataset"),
  varSelectInput("col", "Pick a column", NULL)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    dataset <- NULL
    while (is.null(names(dataset))) {
      dataset <- sample(ls("package:datasets"), 1)
      dataset <- get(dataset, "package:datasets")
    }
    global_data(dataset)
  })
  
  observeEvent(global_data(), {
    updateVarSelectInput(session, "col", data = global_data())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @Thanks a lot. I didn't know there are global reactive values in shiny.